# how to mysql GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I have those 2 tables

id_of_orders

```
id_order| time              | username | price
35      |2013-08-11 15:03:01|          |0.00
36      |2013-08-21 12:43:31|skata     |0.00
37      |2013-08-21 12:43:55|skata     |12.00
```

orders

```
order_id  | product |   ulika   
35        |frento   |zaxari,fountoukia,troufa
35        |frento   |zaxari,kakao
35        |frento   |
36        |frapes   |zaxari
37        |frento   |
35        |frapes   |
```

I want for a specific product to return all the record's data that contain it
I use GROUP_CONCAT but it does not return all the values of the product.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['proions'])){
    $query= "SELECT i.id_order, i.time, i.username, i.price,  GROUP_CONCAT(o.product) as PRO
    FROM id_of_orders i INNER JOIN orders o
    ON i.id_order = o.order_id
    WHERE o.product = '$_SESSION[proions]'";
    $query .=" GROUP BY i.id_order" ;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
```

For example if i try to collect the record's data that contains 'frento' i get those results . I miss the product 'frapes' .

```
35: -> 2013-08-11 15:03:01 0.00 frento,frento,frento
37: -> 2013-08-21 12:43:55 skata 12.00 frento
```

Comment: I think you dont need here group_concat you can use the following query I think this is what you want: SELECT * FROM orders,id_of_orders WHERE orders.id_order = id_of_orders.order_id AND id_of_orders.order_id in( SELECT order_id FROM orders where product = 'frento' ); sorry you may want to use in ()

Comment: i tried this one but it seems it does not work at all  $query = "SELECT * FROM orders,id_of_orders 
 WHERE orders.id_order = id_of_orders.order_id
 AND orders.product = '$_SESSION[proions]'"

Comment: You need to use an *outer*, rather than an *inner*, join.  See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: this should work: $query = "SELECT * FROM orders,id_of_orders WHERE orders.order_id = id_of_orders.id_order AND orders.product = '$_SESSION[proions]'"

Comment: you should use same name field in both table order_id this way you will avoid this kind of issues.

Comment: also I would rename the table `id_of_orders` to `order_details` It is very important to use simple names that describe exactly what the table contains. And it will be much more easier to understand in the next time you will use this table or someone else will use this table.

Comment: So, you want a (LEFT) [OUTER] JOIN, right? - not an INNER one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is filtering all the rows just on the product.  You need to move that comparison to a `having` clause:

```
SELECT i.id_order, i.time, i.username, i.price, GROUP_CONCAT(o.product) as PRO
FROM id_of_orders i INNER JOIN
     orders o
     ON i.id_order = o.order_id
GROUP BY i.id_order
HAVING max(o.product = '$_SESSION[proions]'") > 0;
```

This will return all products for an order where at least one of the rows matches the product you want.